# radio button not shows updated value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to update values from form except gender value all updates.
Gender value is not updating
here is code for gender radio button.

```
<label>
Gender:  </label> 
   <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male" required> Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female" required> Female
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="other" required> Other
```

I'fetching value of form using js function which send it to update function.

```
var gender = $('#gender').val();
```

what mistake I had made?

Comment: because there are duplicate ID use class instead or change to unique ID. you can have id female for female and id male for male to make it unique

Comment: __ID must be unique__

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id

Comment: Make ID unique and `$(':radio[name="gender"]:checked').val();`

Comment: @Tushar How about going with the detailed answer or marking this as closest dulicate ?

Comment: @Rayon There is one answer already posted. Feel free to add detailed answer or close if you get suitable dupe target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
// Get the value from a set of radio buttons
$('input:radio[name="gender"]:checked').val();
```

See also the examples given at http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

try this code working fine at my end

```
  <form >
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"><br>
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female"><br>
  <label for="other">Other</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="other" value="other"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
var gender = $('#gender:checked').val();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dave17/tdk60unr/

i hope it will be helpful.